# Evaluating triple integral $\int_1^{10}\int_0^z\int_0^{z + y}\frac{1}{(x + y + z)^3}\,dx\,dy\,dz$

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus

> Evaluate the triple integral $$\int_1^{10}\int_0^z\int_0^{z + y}\frac{1}{(x + y + z)^3}\,dx\,dy\,dz$$

I am not looking for the entire solution, but hints on how to perform change of variables/any other trick. My first idea was to use $u = x + y + z$, but I don't know how to properly calculate the new limits: if $u = x + y + z$, then is the new lower bound of $dx$ integral $u(0, y, z) = y + z$? In any case I think that there is a snappier trick for substitution other than the $u$ I proposed.

Comment: $(x+a)^{-3}$ can be integrated as is

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint: the innermost integral is just the integral of $\frac1{(x+a)^3},$ where $a=y+z.$